# A superficially divergent diagram in $\phi^4$ interaction, rarely appeared in the literature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, interactions

I'm studying superficial degree of divergence of Feynman diagram and I am confused about some concept.

In particular, its scope is on scalar $\phi^4$ interaction in $3+1$ dimension.

Some literature told that there are only finite numbers of diagrams which contributes divergence of diagrams;superficially divergent which has no subgraph which is superficially divergent. (In here, superficially divergent mean, $\omega \ge 0$ in the sense of power counting.)

Specifically, followings are only considered,
[image: less-than-three-loop basic divergent diagram]

Now, I'll call these *basic divergent diagram*. Note that I want to keep the sense of above context with its definition when I use this term.

The point where I confused is why they didn't mention the tetrahedral diagram, one of the three-loop four-point diagram, as a kind of *basic divergent diagram*.

[image: dd]

In here, the arrowed lines are corresponding to a propagator incident to exterior vertex.

You could see that it doesn't contain superficialy divergent subgraph, but it's superficially divergent because $\omega = 3 \times 4 - 2 \times 6 =0$.

I think this is because it is not chosen in common renormalization scheme. Whatever the reason is, I think it should be also considered as *basic divergence diagram*.

..Or Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: And I can think of another 3 loop diagram with four external legs that is superficially divergent. Just take your diagram (c) add a vertex on each propagator and connect them.

Comment: @octonion Yes that is superficially divergent. However, it is not basic because it contains divergent subgraph.

Comment: Fair enough, I see what you are trying to say. However it would be best to link to the literature you are talking about that claims that all divergences in phi4 arise from combinations of only 3 diagrams. Either it is simply wrong or they have a different definition of subgraph than you, so it is hard to tell without seeing the actual statement they are making

Comment: I realize (b) also have divergent subgraph (c). Maybe I misunderstood something.. I'll check it in the morning.

Comment: (c) may not be a subgraph of (b). Because it is not inserted properly. (Its two lines are merged and makes one loop.)

Comment: Isn't that diagram a four point function?

Comment: @SounakSinha Yes. The fish diagram (c) is also four-point function.